Designing a 48V Phantom Power Supply for Microphone Preamps with +17V Input
I'm working on designing a phantom power supply for a microphone preamp. Originally, I planned to use the MC34063A, but it only provides a maximum output of 40V, whereas I need 48V. My input voltage is +17V.
Could you provide recommendations on suitable topologies or integrated circuits to achieve the conversion from 17V DC to 48V DC?
Thank you!

At what current? With what regulation? Also note that switching supplies might introduce noise into the audio.

Suitable topology, yes. Which chip to buy is off-topic. Please edit the question before it gets closed.

You'll not only need a suitable boost regulator, you'll also need some kind of filtering to get a clean enough supply for microphone audio.
For 48 V you'll need 63 V filter caps which can be on the large size at the values you'd need for good filtering.
This article from Analog Devices shows one way to solve this by using a capacitance multiplier to reduce the size of the needed caps.
Something like this should do what you want.

Depending on the output current required, this could be as simple as a 555 oscillator driving a multi-stage charge pump, filtered and regulated down to 48 V.  No transformer, inductors, or inductive spikes.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cockcroft%E2%80%93Walton_generator
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_multiplier

According to IEC Standard 61938:2018, the current for phantom power can range from 7 mA to a maximum of 10 mA. The microphone impedance is typically low, around 200 ohms, but it may vary depending on the specific microphone.
